# PHP script passing email files as STDIN to another PHP parser causing intermittent errors

Tags: php, email, parsing, stdin

I have an email script that is parsing bounced emails just fine.  Now I have written another script to read all the emails from a particular user account and pass each email file to my parsing script.  It works on about 50% of the emails I pass to the parser....the other 50% error as if the STDIN content is being treated PHP code or a PHP command.  I can't figure out why its doing this:

Script to read files and pass to parser:

```
<?php
$extScript = "php -f /home/myUser/dev/scripts/email/bouncedEmail.php" ;
$dir = "/home/myUser/mail/myDomain.com/register/cur/" ;
$emails = scandir($dir) ;

echo "\n" ;
foreach ($emails as $email) {
  if (!preg_match("/^\./", $email) && !preg_match("/^\.\./", $email)) {
    echo "Processing: $email\n" ;
    $emailContent = file_get_contents($dir.$email) ;
    passthru("{$extScript} <<< '{$emailContent}'") ;
  }
}
?>
```

And the parser:

```
<?php
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "bouncedEmails.log");
include '/home/myUser/dev/scripts/includes.php' ;

// empty vars
$toEmails = [] ;
for ($i=0; $i < count($lines); $i++){

    // look out for special headers
    if (preg_match("/^From: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
        list($fName,$fAddy) = explode("<",$matches[1]) ;
        $fAddy = str_replace(">","",$fAddy) ;
        //error_log("FROM: " .$lines[$i],0) ;
    }

    if (preg_match("/^To: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
      $lineInfo = explode(" ",$matches[1]) ;
      foreach ($lineInfo as $info) {
        if (strpos($info,'@') !== false) {
          $toEmail = str_replace("<","",$info) ;
          $toEmail = str_replace(">","",$toEmail) ;
          if (!in_array($toEmail,$toEmails) && strpos($toEmail,'whipster') === false) {
            $toEmails[] = $toEmail ;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    if (preg_match("/^REFID: (.*)/",$lines[$i],$matches)) {
        $uid = $matches[1] ;
    }
  }
}

foreach ($toEmails as $email) {
  $uc = writeDB($email) ;
  if ($uc == 0) {
    $msg = "$email : not found in db" ;
  } else {
    $msg = "$email : removed from db" ;
  }
  error_log("Bounced Email: $msg",0) ;
}

// update any DB records with matched email addresses
function writeDB($to) {
  $query = "UPDATE userTable SET user_email='',user_emailVerify=0 WHERE user_email=?" ;
  list($upCount,$upError) = dbUpdate($query,array($to)) ;
  return $upCount ;
}

unset($pdo) ;
?>
```

As I mentioned, this is processing about 50% of the emails without issue, but the other 50% are erroring out with one of the two sets of errors:

```
sh: line 36: 550-5.1.1: command not found 
sh: line 37: 550: command
not found sh: line 38: .: filename argument required
.: usage: . filename [arguments]
```

OR

```
sh: -c: line 34: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 34: `Reason: There was an error while attempting to deliver your message with [Subject: "Registration email verification"] to paige493@verizon.net. MTA p3plsmtpout001.prod.phx3.secureserver.net received this response from the destination host IP - 67.195.228.86 -  554 , 554 delivery error: dd This user doesn't have a verizon.net account (paige493@verizon.net) [-9] - mta4110.aol.mail.gq1.yahoo.com'
```

I then changed for script foreach loop to this:

```
foreach ($emails as $email) {
  if (!preg_match("/^\./", $email) && !preg_match("/^\.\./", $email)) {
    echo "Processing: $email\n" ;
    $dirFile = $dir.$email ;
    passthru("{$extScript} < {$dirFilel}");
  }
}
```

And now every file errors out with:

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
sh: -c: line 0: `php -f /home/myUser/dev/scripts/email/bouncedEmail.php <<< '
```

What is causing file contents to be read by the parser to be treated as code versus raw STDIN file info?
How can I fix this or whats the better method here?

Answer (score 1):

I would use base64 on first example. You're messing with shell here:

```
<?php
$extScript = "php -f /home/myUser/dev/scripts/email/bouncedEmail.php" ;
$dir = "/home/myUser/mail/myDomain.com/register/cur/" ;
$emails = scandir($dir) ;

echo "\n" ;
foreach ($emails as $email) {
  if (!preg_match("/^\./", $email) && !preg_match("/^\.\./", $email)) {
  echo "Processing: $email\n" ;
  $emailContent = base64_encode(file_get_contents($dir.$email));
  passthru("{$extScript} <<< '{$emailContent}'") ;
}
}
```

You need to use `base64_decode` afterwards in your parser to read the stdin. I cannot supply an example, because your provided code is incomplete.

EDIT:
You can simply read stdin like this: $lines = base64_decode(stream_get_contents(STDIN)); and continue using the old script

Comment: I got excited and thought it worked.  I thought it worked because there were no errors, however the script captured zero TO email addresses in the log file.

Comment: By doing `base64_encode` the email is piped into the parser script but the parser script is no longer able to explode the STDIN into individual lines.  Most emails are around 200+ lines long (after the explode), but when I count the lines being processed in the foreach loop, it only counts two lines then ends, and the wrapper script moves on to the next file to process.

Comment: You can simply read stdin like this: $lines = base64_decode(stream_get_contents(STDIN)); and continue using the old script

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my main script, the one that pass the email files to the parser script, had a typo in it.  I must have looked at it 100 times and only saw it when I was trying to add code to a specific variable that I saw the variable had a `1` added to it.

```
foreach ($emails as $email) {
  if (!preg_match("/^\./", $email) && !preg_match("/^\.\./", $email)) {
    echo "Processing: $email\n" ;
    $dirFile = $dir.$email ;
    passthru("{$extScript} < {$dirFilel}");
  }
}
```

`$dirFile1` was the typo, removed the 1 and it worked just fine!

GRRRRRRRrrrrrrr!